# How can I create a contact (quickly) with multiple contact subtypes?

Tags: contacts, contact-types

**The need**

I need to create contacts that have more than one contact subtype assigned. For example *Student + Parent*.

**Slow approaches**

- If I create the contact directly from the menu link *Contacts > New Individual > New Student*, then it is not possible to assign it a second subtype on the immediat form. It is necessary first save the contact and then re-edit to add the second contact subtype.
- Also it's possible to create the contact from the menu link *Contacts > New Individual* and then assign the needed contact subtypes on the immediat form. But this option is confusing by our users as they hope to create an Student or a Parent but not a Individual.

**There is a more direct approach to this need?**

Maybe I expected to find the possibility to add an item to the menu of contacts that allow us to create directly a contact with multiple contact subtypes with and URL like `civicrm/contact/add?ct=Individual&cst=Student+Parent&reset=1`.

Comment: Is there any major reason why contact subtype selector field is hidden if we create a contact subtype directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This patch is enough for me and is ready for 4.7.10:

[Show contact subtype field when create contact subtype](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19088)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using drupal then you could use webforms for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this approach but you should be able to create a CiviCRM profile under (/civicrm/admin/uf/group/add?action=add&reset=1). Then add all the fields you need (incl. subtypes) and then use the URL of the profile(something like civicrm/profile/create?gid=XX&reset=1) if you want to create contacts.

For quicker access you could add a link to the profile in the navigation menu or put the profile in a drupal block.